# What is CPU minutes (Web Hosting)?

Tags: web-hosting, cpu

When I ask a support from a web hosting company I receive this part.

> You can use up to 300+ CPU minutes without causing any issues

What is the meaning of CPU minutes? How it calculate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various resources are required for hosting a website - including Storage, CPU and Bandwidth.

"CPU" is generally a reference to the "processing recources".

When in a shared environment, an environment where several sites are sharing resources, the CPU is a reference to the server's processor.

Some sites require more processing because either:
1. they are busier; and/or
2. they need more processing to serve the page.

For example: A static site (a site which just gives returns a requested file or files) uses very little processing. Whereas a dynamic site (which assembles the page when requested and then returns it - e.g. wordpress sites, etc) generally requires much more processing by the server.

Limits are usually placed on resources to prevent/deter a site from using more than its fair share to the detriment of the other sites.

In that context, I suspect the 'CPU minute' is a way of allocating access to the server's processor and as part of a limit to keep things fair for all sites using it. If your site uses more than its allocation, you pay more.

It is probably calculated by adding up the time your site uses the server's processor - probably over a period like each month.

Comment: and dynamic sites that are poorly programmed will require even more cpu time, especially if the code contains an endless loop that is executed.

Comment: @Mike +1 That would be a real danger here. Personally, I love static sites for their speed and low use of resources - though I appreciate that they are not always appropriate.